# Displaying the name of the valuable and not the value of it

Tags: vb.net, variables

I am making a School Council voting system where the user enters the vote preference for 5 candidates. The program then adds these up and displays the candidate with the lowest score as the winner. It is at this bit I am getting stuck. My code is only displaying the value of the candidate with the lowest score and not the name that that score belongs to. This is what I have written so far:

```
Public Class EnterVotes

Dim winner As Integer = Candidate1Total


Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click

End Sub

Private Sub VScrollBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim int As Integer
    int = NumericUpDownC1V1.Value
    int = NumericUpDownC1V2.Value
    int = NumericUpDownC1V3.Value
    int = NumericUpDownC1V4.Value
    int = NumericUpDownC1V5.Value

    Dim Candidate1Total As Integer
    Dim Candidate2Total As Integer
    Dim Candidate3Total As Integer
    Dim Candidate4Total As Integer
    Dim Candidate5Total As Integer

    Try

        Candidate1Total = NumericUpDownC1V1.Value + (NumericUpDownC1V2.Value * 2) + (NumericUpDownC1V3.Value * 3) + (NumericUpDownC1V4.Value * 4) + (NumericUpDownC1V5.Value * 5)
        Candidate2Total = NumericUpDownC2V1.Value + (NumericUpDownC2V2.Value * 2) + (NumericUpDownC2V3.Value * 3) + (NumericUpDownC2V4.Value * 4) + (NumericUpDownC2V5.Value * 5)
        Candidate3Total = NumericUpDownC3V1.Value + (NumericUpDownC3V2.Value * 2) + (NumericUpDownC3V3.Value * 3) + (NumericUpDownC3V4.Value * 4) + (NumericUpDownC3V5.Value * 5)
        Candidate4Total = NumericUpDownC4V1.Value + (NumericUpDownC4V2.Value * 2) + (NumericUpDownC4V3.Value * 3) + (NumericUpDownC4V4.Value * 4) + (NumericUpDownC4V5.Value * 5)
        Candidate5Total = NumericUpDownC5V1.Value + (NumericUpDownC5V2.Value * 2) + (NumericUpDownC5V3.Value * 3) + (NumericUpDownC5V4.Value * 4) + (NumericUpDownC5V5.Value * 5)

        Label7.Text = Candidate1Total
        Label8.Text = Candidate2Total
        Label9.Text = Candidate3Total
        Label10.Text = Candidate4Total
        Label11.Text = Candidate5Total

    Catch

    End Try


    If Candidate2Total < winner Then
        winner = Candidate2Total

    End If
    If Candidate3Total < winner Then
        winner = Candidate3Total

    End If
    If Candidate4Total < winner Then
        winner = Candidate4Total

    End If
    If Candidate5Total < winner Then
        winner = Candidate5Total

    End If
    Label3.Text = winner
```

Comment: Does that language, whatever it is, not have arrays and loops?

Comment: You should tag a language, it is VB.Net if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays for the candidates and vote counters:

```
Dim CandidateTotal(5) As Integer
Dim NumericUpDown(5)(5) As Integer
```

Then modify your program accordingly. You can just ignore the first array element (0) and use 1-5. Modify the program to use CandidateTotal(n) where n=candidate and NumericUpDown(n)(x) where n=candidate and x=vote in place of your existing code and then when you find the winner you'll have the index (number 1-5) which is the candidate who won.

Comment: Like this?!?!   Im a bit rusty with Arrays.         Dim CandidateTotal(5) As Integer
        Dim NumericUpDown(5) As Integer
        CandidateTotal(1) = Candidate1Total
        CandidateTotal(2) = Candidate2Total
        CandidateTotal(3) = Candidate3Total
        CandidateTotal(4) = Candidate4Total
        CandidateTotal(5) = Candidate5Total



        If CandidateTotal(2) < winner Then
            winner = CandidateTotal(2)

        End If
        If CandidateTotal(3) < winner Then
            winner = CandidateTotal(3)

        End If
        If CandidateTotal(4) < winner The

Comment: Bit stuck on defining the array for the NumericUpDown

Comment: I edited my answer, didn't catch that each candidate had 5 votes, you'll use a two dimensional array. Check at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 for help on using arrays.

Comment: You really don't have to know much about arrays to use the solution I gave. This should get you closer to your goal. Where you have Candidate1Total, change it to CandidateTotal(1), Candidate2Total becomes CandidateTotal(2) and so on. NumericUpDownC1V1 becomes NumericUpDown(1)(1), NumericUpDownC1V2 becomes NumericUpDown(1)(2) and so on. You can make it cleaner using loops, but for now since you're just learning just make the substitutions in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The winner variable should be set right before the first if statement. I don't understand how your code compile.

You would need to store two variable, one for the score and one for the name.

```
Dim winnerScore As Integer = Candidate1Total
Dim winnerName As String = "Name of candidate 1"

If Candidate2Total < winnerScore Then
    winnerScore = Candidate2Total
    winnerName As String = "Name of candidate 2"

End If
If Candidate3Total < winnerScore Then
    winnerScore = Candidate3Total
    winnerName As String = "Name of candidate 3"
End If
If Candidate4Total < winnerScore Then
    winnerScore = Candidate4Total
    winnerName As String = "Name of candidate 4"
End If
If Candidate5Total < winnerScore Then
    winnerScore = Candidate5Total
    winnerName As String = "Name of candidate 5"
End If

Label3.Text = winnerScore
' Display winnerName somewhere
```

In your code, you would set the winnerName properly. I also don't know where you want to display the name.

Your "int" variable is pointeless, you can remove that.

As some stated, an array would be a good idea.